# What is "Verbose_name" and "Ordering" in class Meta? And please explain a little about Meta Class in django

Tags: python, django

```py
from django.db import models
import uuid
class Book(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    isbn=models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, 
    primary_key=True)
    writer=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering=['name']
        ordering='User MetaData
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering

Comment: Also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-options

Answer (score 1):

With class Meta you can give to your model metata such as database table name or ordering options. You can check it out in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#meta-options)

By using "verbose_name" in class Meta you can specify human-readable name for singular object. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.verbose_name)

By using 'ordering' in class Meta you can specify in which order you will get list of objects. By ['-field_name'] you specify descending order. By ['field_name'] you specify ascending order. You can make ordering by several fields: ordering = ['field1', 'field2']. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.ordering)

Answer (score 0):

1.Model Meta is basically used to change the behavior of your model fields like changing order options,verbose_name and lot of other options. It’s completely optional to add Meta class in your model.

2.Verbose_name is a human-readable name for the field.

3.Ordering takes a list of string values, which are model fields. It's used to define the ordering of objects of a model. When the objects of this model are retrieved, they will be present in this ordering.